# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config' outside django app

Tags: python, django, cookiecutter-django

I am using `cookiecutter-django` on my project and having problem while trying to import settings from config outside app.
Getting error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'`
**Project structure**

```bash
project
 ┣ .envs
 ┃ ┗ .local
 ┃ ┃ ┣ .bot
 ┃ ┃ ┣ .django
 ┣ bot
 ┃ ┣ __init__.py
 ┃ ┗ bot.py
 ┣ compose
 ┃ ┣ local
 ┃ ┃ ┣ django
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ Dockerfile
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ start
 ┃ ┃ ┗ pytelegrambot
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ Dockerfile
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ start
 ┣ config
 ┃ ┣ settings
 ┃ ┃ ┣ __init__.py
 ┃ ┃ ┣ base.py
 ┃ ┃ ┣ local.py
 ┃ ┣ __init__.py
 ┃ ┣ urls.py
 ┃ ┗ wsgi.py
 ┣ project
 ┃ ┣ app
 ┃ ┃ ┣ migrations
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ __init__.py
 ┃ ┃ ┣ admin.py
 ┃ ┃ ┣ apps.py
 ┃ ┃ ┣ signals.py
 ┃ ┃ ┣ models.py
 ┃ ┃ ┗ views.py
 ┣ requirements
 ┃ ┣ base.txt
 ┣ README.md
 ┣ local.yml
 ┣ manage.py
```

**bot.py**

```py
import telebot
from config.settings.base import env

bot = telebot.TeleBot(env('BOT_TOKEN'))

def send_welcome(message):
    print(message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.infinity_polling()
```

**signals.py**

```py
from bot.bot import send_welcome

@receiver(post_save, sender=Model)
def translate(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    send_wlcome("Hi")
```

Here I am sending message on telegram bot when object created. If I try to use `os.environ['BOT_TOKEN']` it gives me another error from **signals.py**  `KeyError: 'BOT_TOKEN'`. BOT_TOKEN is located in `.envs/.local/.bot`
Please, can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your code in project directory.

Django cookiecutter defines the root path project to Project directory, so all code have to be set there.

In manage.py file, you can see the code which make the project directory as root path. You can change it, but i do not sure it is a good idea.

Comment: Can you clarify your answer please? tried `sys.path.append(str('path/to/code'))` but didn't help

Comment: you do not understand. bot.py is a independant code, so, you have to add path to other lib inside directly. So you add the path or you import in relative way: `from ..config.settings.base import env`.